# Trigger two actions with an onclick

Tags: android, methods, onclick, onclicklistener

I want to use 2 methods in the same time with onclick but the method "deleteNotification()" works before "buttonPause()". It takes two click in the button to have the second method...
Can you help me please ?`

This is my code :

```
btn_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!playPause) {

                buttonPause();
                deleteNotification();

            }

private void buttonPause(){
    btn_play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pausevt);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    playPause = true;
}

private void deleteNotification(){
    final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    //la suppression de la notification se fait grâce a son ID
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
}
```

Comment: When you want to do more than one work simultaneously use `Thread`

Comment: Do you mean that deleteNotification() is called before buttonPause() when onClick is fired ? Because that's not really possible.

Comment: Yes delete is called before